# How do I declare a 2 digit integer with leading zero openvms

Tags: openvms

How do I declare a 2 digit integer with leading zero `openvms`

Example:

```
$month = 01
$month = month + 1
$write sys$output month
```

I want month to now be 02.

Answer (score 2):

You don't. A symbol can be either a string or an integer. A string can contain zeroes or other characters wherever you want them. An integer just contains a numeric value.

You can format an integer as a string with leading zeroes using the `f$fao` lexical function:

```
$ FormattedMonth = f$fao( "!2ZB", month )
```

Ref: [f$fao](http://h71000.www7.hp.com/doc/84final/9996/9996pro_95.html).